# list.removeWhere, to remove only 1 occurence of condition

Tags: flutter, dart

suppose i have a list:
`List? myList = [{Person: 1},{Person: 1},{Person: 2},{Person: 3},{Person: 4},{Person: 5}];`

I would like to remove the first occurrence of '1' using list.removeWhere.

How can I achieve this? I tried this one below but it removed all '1's.

`myList.removeWhere((e) => e['Person'] == 1);`

Comment: `Person` is a class here? or just String

Comment: just a String sir

Answer (score 4):

You can get the first item then remove it from list. `removeWhere` removes all elements that satisfy its condition

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  List? myList = [
    {"Person": 1},
    {"Person": 1},
    {"Person": 2},
    {"Person": 3},
    {"Person": 4},
    {"Person": 5}
  ];

  final item = myList.firstWhere((e) => e['Person'] == 1);
  myList.remove(item);

  print(myList);
}
```

Or

```dart
  final int item = myList.indexWhere((e) => e['Person'] == 1);
  myList.removeAt(item);
```

Comment: forgot about that .firstWhere function. and this totally works! thanks man!

Comment: Np, you can explore more about [List](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/List/List.html)

Comment: i guess myList.removeWhere.single()  will also work the same as you want.

Comment: I cant find any `myList.removeWhere.single()` on dart core